# How can I handle POST request and print output on the same page?

Tags: python, django

I serve a page which has a button and on a button click Django executes script (Ansible playbook) and prints stdout to the same page. It's kind of a very simplistic web-interface for Ansible. Ansible is located on the same machine where Django is.

Right now Django view renders this page(HTML template) on HTTP GET, and when button is clicked HTTP POST is invoked which does all Ansible stuff, grabs stdout and renders the same template with additional context.

The only problem I have at the moment is manually refreshing after clicking that button. If you hit the button and after that refresh your browser, POST is invoked again including all the consequences (Ansible playbook etc.)

What options do I have to solve this problem ? I really need stdout printed on the same page so redirecting to a different page is not an option.

Looks very similar to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
<input type="submit" value="{% if status == 1 %}Shut Down{% else %}Bring Up{% endif %}" id="submit01"/>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX to send asynchronous requests to your django server, have them processed, and then return the result to your existing page.

Answer (score 1):

You should include a [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) in your view after the POST request to prevent this from happening.